# Is it possible to update Facebook opengraph data on posts that have already been posted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have made an FB post on a page that I manage.  The posted contained a link to a website I manage.  FB has scraped the opengraph data from the website, and posted the data on the timeline of my page, as expected.

I have since edited the opengraph data on my website.  I want to find a way to tell Facebook to refresh the opengraph data it read from my website in the *existing* post on my timeline.  I do not want to delete the existing post, because it has lots of likes associated with it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it.  Click on the timestamp associated with the post.  This will take you to a view of the Facebook object.  Click the down arrow menu activator in the top right.  Select "More options".  Select "Refresh share attachment".  Done :)